# Selecting text within two patterns using the command line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract text from within a large file, however I am only interested in the text between two patterns.

Sample text looks like this:

```
<account>0409</account><name>Charles</name><type>R</type><accountStatus>active</accountStatus>
```

My desired output should be **only** the text within the name tag, nothing before and nothing after. In example:

Output: Charles

In this case the starting pattern is `<name>` and ending pattern `</name>`

How can I achieve this using grep/sed/awk?

Comment: `sed -n 's/^ *<name>\(.*)<\/name> *$/\1/p'`

Comment: I get the following response: sed: -e expression #1, char 46: Unmatched ( or \(

Comment: The second paren isn't escaped.

Comment: `sed -n 's/^.*<name>\(.*\)<\/name\>.*$/\1/p'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</?name>' '!(NR%2)' file
Charles
```

The above will work whether or not there are newlines anywhere in your input file and no matter how many times `<name>...</name>` appears on one line or split across lines, it only requires that `<name>` and `</name>` always appear as pairs in the input file:

```
$ cat file
<name>Charles</name><name>William</name>
<name>Edward
</name>
<name>   John Boy Walton   </name>
$ awk -v RS='</?name>' '!(NR%2)' file
Charles
William
Edward

   John Boy Walton
```

and if you want to strip any leading/trailing white space from the names it's a simple tweak:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]*</?name>[[:space:]]*' '!(NR%2)' file
Charles
William
Edward
John Boy Walton
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"<|>" '/name/ {print $3}' file
Charles
```

If all data is on one line do:

```
awk -v RS="<" -F\> '/name/{print $2;exit}' file
Charles
```

Comment: The text is all in one line, it is not separated by newlines. Do you think that will alter the behavior of your solution? I am getting nothing back using that command

Comment: @user3120518 see my updated post.  I also edited your original post.